# How to separate a particular part from a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

If I want to fetch the refresh token value (i.e abcdefghijklmp) from the below JSON Object, how can I do that?
Example:

```
let headers = {
    Cookie: [
      '_fbp=70924796; 
_ga=GA1.390; 
_gcl_au=1.78.1649398389; 
_gid=148122.1649398390; 
refresh_token=abcdefghijklmp'
    ]
}
```

Comment: headers.Cookie[0].match(/refresh_token=([^;]*)/)[1]

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string:

```js
let str = "_fbp=70924796; _ga=GA1.390; _gcl_au=1.78.1649398389; _gid=148122.1649398390; refresh_token=abcdefghijklmp"
let tokenArr = str.split("; ")
        .map(s => s.split("="))
        .find(split => split[0] === "refresh_token")

if (tokenArr && tokenArr.length > 1) {
   let token = tokenArr[1]
   console.log(token)
} else {
   console.log("Token not found")
}
```

Comment: How to implement if the position of the refresh token is different. It may be in any xyz position

Comment: In that case you could use `map` and `find` on the splitted string (check edited answer)